# bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <PyTime:6/1/2015 9:00:00 AM>

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, win32com

I'm scraping calendar items from Outlook with Python, using win32com.client, and also using pymongo to insert the data into Mongo. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mongo_test.py", line 55, in <module>
    calItems.insert({"Subject" : appointmentItem.Subject , "Start" : appointmentItem.Start , "End" : appointmentItem.End })
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1926, in insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "C:\Puthon27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 430, in_insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.codec_options, sock_info)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <PyTime:6/1/2015 9:00:00 AM>
```

The `appointmentItem.Start` and `appointmentItem.End` calls output a Date data type, but Mongo seems to be unable to read them as Dates. If I wrap these two in `str()` then they are successfully inserted into the database as strings, but I really need to put them in as datetimes. Any ideas about how I can accomplish this? I can post more of my code if it would be helpful.

Comment: have you tried `new Date()`???

Comment: Hm, thanks for the response, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Researching that lead me to `datetime.datetime.strptime` though, and that is what eventually did the trick.